# How to save variable data in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make this so that is saves every time I close the app. The tutorials I found are not clear for me, can anyone please assist me? If needed, here's how my variable I want saved is defined:

```
private var coins = 0
```

[Here is the GitHub link if needed](https://github.com/Zytron1228/Tile_Lottery/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/tilelottery/MainActivity.kt), which goes straight to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) to save and retrieve simple data

save data

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putInt("MY_COINS", coins)
    apply()
}
```

Read data

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
val coins = sharedPref.getInt("MY_COINS"), defaultValue)
```

Comment: Thanks but, where should I put these pieces of code? I'm assuming the load data part can go at the beginning of override fun onCreate after "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)" but where would the save data part go?

Comment: Put the data saving code after the last update of the coins variable and it depends on your need

Comment: I'm having trouble with the code, would you mind telling me what some of these terms are, like "activity?" sorry I'm really new to Kotlin and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences for state management or save data in key-value pair.

```
lateinit var shared : SharedPreferences

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spactivity)

        shared = getSharedPreferences("CoinsDB" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var coins = 0
```

For Save

```
 val edit = shared.edit()
 edit.putInt("coins" , coins )
 edit.apply()
```

For retrieve or read

```
val coinsValue = shared.getInt("coins")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using storage in files if that isn't a problem for you.